# Exchange 2010 only allows 1 IMAP/POP3 account to be logged in

Tags: exchange-2010, imap

We just moved to Exchange 2010 and the IMAP/POP3 accounts are only allowing one person to be logged into them at a time. The second person that tries to login gets an invalid username/password window.

We are in need of setting 6 people up on our `support@domain.com` email so that they can all respond to these emails. They are all set up with IMAP so that they can send replies back to our customers using this same email.

Does anyone know what setting would make so multiple people can be actively logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your `IMAPMaxConcurrency` settings for `Set-ThrottlingPolicy`.

> The IMAPMaxConcurrency parameter specifies how many concurrent
>   connections an IMAP user can have against an Exchange server at one
>   time. A connection is held from the moment a request is received until
>   a response is sent in its entirety to the requestor. If users attempt
>   to make more concurrent requests than their policy allows, the new
>   connection attempt fails. However, the existing connections remain
>   valid. The IMAPMaxConcurrency parameter has a valid range from 0
>   through 2147483647 inclusive. To indicate that the number of
>   concurrent connections should be unthrottled (no limit), this value
>   should be set to $null.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298094.aspx

Comment: I changed the limit on the IMAP/Connection tab to the max and its still not allowing more then one user to login. This is boggling...